# How to generate flatfile with zero records when there are no records in source?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics

I'm doing incremental data load from relatioal db to dynamically created flat file. Suppose if there are no new records in source the mapping not creating target file. I need a empty Target file if there are no records fetched From source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cmd task which will kick off on a condition.

1. in cmd task just put this command

```
touch /location/empty_file.txt
```

2. Link main session to this command task. Double click on link and add below condition to link.

```
$yourMainSessionName.SrcSuccessRows = 0
```

So, this command task will activate only when your main session pulls 0 rows.